# Too few Android events in the GA4 historical data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have several apps running GA4, both iOS and Android. iOS is working as intended.

We are utilizing a lot of Custom Definitions (40) and only a few of the Google standard events.

We are seeing far too few Android events in the historical data, but only for some of the Android apps. For example, we could see a 50%/50% split between Android and iOS in the real-time data, but in the historical data this is a 5%/95% split between Android and iOS. This is not just for yesterday's historical data, but for all data regardless of time frame.

We suspect that there could be an issue on Googles end with the transition of data from the real-time system to the historical system.

Our tracking setup is as follows:

Send events from App to Firebase -> Firebase Integrates with Google Analytics -> Custom Definitions are defined in Google Analytics

Has anyone experienced this issue with Android or something similar?

We can see our Android events in debug-mode.